# How to remove circular fluorescent light bulb?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

Circular fluorescent light bulb burned out and I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction. You can see in the picture below that there are wires connected to a clasp. Removing the wires is the key part that I'm struggling with. I'm able to pop the bulb out but it's connected by the clasp / wires.

I was able to open the clasp a little bit by removing a small screw in the hole then prying it open. However, even when the clasp is open, there are still wires connected to the bulb. I'm completely unfamiliar with this bulb and its hard to assess the situation being on the ceiling.

Anyone have any ideas or familiarity with this? I'm not sure if I'm expected to open the clasp to remove the wires, or if I remove the wires at the point of the connection with the clasp.

Thanks for any help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's been a while since I had to face a circle bulb, but normally they have pins sticking out, so the bit of plastic with the wires should slide off (unplug from) the pins. But you may have a different variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a push-on pin-and-socket connector. Wiggle the connector body gently in a circular motion, or possibly pry at it to make it slide off the pins. Pull upward and toward the center of the circle. Here's a photo of a lamp (image from ballastshop.com) with the connector removed.

Or, compare the price of a new lamp against the price of a new LED fixture..

[image: circline fluorescent lamp]

Comment: Plus the three metal tabs on the inner circumference that help hold it in place. Might have to tug a bit after the connector is undone.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly right!!!